# DoCallBack CrossAppDomainDelegate behavior for non-static delegates

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, appdomain, applicationdomain

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
// Create a new application domain
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");

Worker work = new Worker();

// if Worker class is marked as 'MarshalByRefObject', this will run in current
// appdomain.
// if Worker class is NOT marked as 'MarshalByRefObject' and is marked as
// 'Serializable', this will run in a new appdomain.
ad.DoCallBack(work.PrintDomain);
// or ad.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(work.PrintDomain));

// But for static methods:
// If ppp method is static, no marking is required and it will run in
// a new AppDomain.
ad.DoCallBack(Worker.ppp);
```

How do we explain this behavior of `DoCallBack`?

1. Why is the non-static method `PrintDomain` executed in the current domain when the `Worker` class is marked `MarshalByRefObject`?
2. Why is the non-static method `PrintDomain` executed in a new AppDomain when the `Worker` class is marked `Serializable`?
3. Why doesn't the static method need any markings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is the non-static method PrintDomain executed in the current domain when the Worker class is marked MarshalByRefObject?

Because that's what MBRO does, it creates a proxy for the object that you created in your primary appdomain.  Which marshals the call from the secondary appdomain to the appdomain that owns the object, the primary appdomain.

> Why is the non-static method PrintDomain executed in a new AppDomain when the Worker class is marked Serializable?

Because that scenario does *not* use a proxy.  The object itself is marshaled from the primary to the secondary appdomain.  Possible because you marked it [Serializable].  The call therefore executes in the secondary appdomain.

> Why doesn't the static method need any markings?

It is unclear what you mean by "markings", but it isn't any different for a static method.  Some code to play with, remove the comment on the base class to compare the two scenarios:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");
        var obj = new WorkerMbro();
        dom.DoCallBack(obj.PrintDomain);
        dom.DoCallBack(obj.PrintDomainStatic);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
[Serializable]
class WorkerMbro /* : MarshalByRefObject */ {
    public void PrintDomain() {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
    public void PrintDomainStatic() {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
}
```

Output as posted:

```
Test
Test
```

Output with the comments removed so the proxy is used:

```
ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
```

Comment: Your method `PrintDomainStatic` is not static. When the proxy is used (`MarshalByRefObject` uncommented) the output is `ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe       Test`